# How to have a "live preview" when changing colors in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I'm a bit used to Photoshop and I just started to learn Illustrator but there's a little thing that's really bothering me.

In Photoshop when you are changing a color you can see it previewed on the object as you're selecting. It helps a lot with choosing the right color. See the following GIF to understand what I mean

[image: PS color changing]

But in Illustrator you have to "apply" the color every time you want to try a slight change. That's very frustrating.

How can I change it to have a "live preview" when changing colors in Illustrator like in Photoshop?

Answer (score 4):

Use the **Color Panel** not the Color Picker.

[image]

The color *picker* is not as directly integrated into the Illustrator UI the way it is in Photoshop. You can easily change all colors using the Color Panel. There's really little need to use the Color Picker in Illustrator.

Comment: I can't get it to work either.
http://goo.gl/4Uxsko
I mean seeing the change BEFORE stopping dragging the little arrow.

Comment: Okay, you do have to *let go* of the mouse for the color to update. There's no way around that.

Comment: In Photoshop you don't.
Are you sure there is no workaround to this?
it's very bothering.

Comment: I'm fairly certain there's no way to get around the *"let go"* aspect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a missing feature in the Adobe Illustrator and unfortunately it seems that's not going to be added in future.

**Instead** you can use "Recolor Artwork" dialog box explained below:

If you select artwork in your Illustrator document, you can then click the Recolor Artwork button in the Control panel or at the bottom of the Color Guide panel.

[image]
There you can easily check the recolor artwork box, at the left bottom of the window, then use color wheel to recolor your object(s) **with a live preview.**

In the Recolor Artwork dialog box, you can edit colors independently or together, merge colors to create tints or shades, “map” existing color groups to the colors in the selected artwork, and much more